# .Net 1.1 Web application is picking up web.config from root folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a .Net 1.1 web application sitting in a folder called C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyTestApp, where 'MyTestApp' is a virtual directory and is configured to be on ASP.Net version 1.1.4322 in IIS 5.1.

In the root directory (C:\inetpub\wwwroot) there is a web.config file for a .Net2.0 application, because the root folder contains some web pages written in .Net2.0.

Whenever I try to access 'MyTestApp' though I get an error...

```
Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section 'connectionStrings'

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config    Line: 17
```

The .Net1.1 application in the MyTestApp folder is trying to access the web.config file in the root folder, and getting upset because it is on a different version. How can I tell the MyTestApp folder NOT to use the web.config file in the root folder, but instead just use the web.config in its own folder?

Is such a thing possible, or is nesting a .Net 1.1 application in a sub-folder under a .Net 2.0 application a no-no?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure your virtual directory for your 1.1 app as a "application" directory.

I am on IIS7, so I am providing this from memory!

If you right click it in IIS, and then click "**Create Application**" that should do the trick.

`Web.config` is always read based on proximity (closest to application first, up through folder structure, right up to `Machine.config`).

Hope this helps.

#### Edit

Checkout the [guide on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138) on creating Virtual Directories. It also touches on creating Applications.

Comment: Alas, it is indeed already created as an application. Tts Application protection level is also set to High (Isolated).

Comment: When you access the virtual directory properties, and click the ASP.NET tab. There should be a button in there to edit the configuration, what configuration file information is listed when you do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [InheritInChildApplications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.inheritinchildapplications(VS.80).aspx) setting in the root web.config and set this to false.

Comment: more info related to this suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367282/disable-web-config-inheritance