# Disable web.config inheritance?

Tags: asp.net

I have a content management application in the root of my website, and I'm trying to use a different app (a billing application) under a sub-folder. Unfortunately, the web.config of the root site is interfering with the sub-app.

Is there a way to just disable web.config inheritance for a sub-folder?

**Update:**
As linked by [Stephen Burris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31474/stephen-b-burris-jr), using the `<location>` tag can prevent inheritance for part of the web config, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    ....
</configSections>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <appSettings>
        ....
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        ....
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        ....
    </system.codedom>
    <system.webServer>
        ....
    </system.webServer>
</location>
<runtime>
    ....
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

The `<configSections>` and `<runtime>` sections will not accept being enclosed in the  tag...so I guess this only does most of the job. Anybody know how to do it better?

Comment: **tldr, don't bother; from 11+ years in the future.** I've in the process of moving applications to *distinct sites* to avoid this sort of nonsense. There is not a clean way to deal with complex inheritance for many reasons: 1) can't disable inheritance of certain sections at all; 2) can't selectively disable inheritance of portions of other sections; 3) suppressing inheritance (where it works) inconsistently blocks inheriting from the grandparent (eg. host config) as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an attribute that you can use in the root web.config file to cause it not to have its contents become inherited by child applications.

inheritInChildApplications

[Blog about inheritInChildApplications](http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2007/05/16/stopping-asp.net-web.config-inheritance.aspx)

[MSDN article on ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarcy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx)

Put the part of the config that is not for inheritance inside

```
<location inheritInChildApplications="false">
     <NotInheritedConfigPart/>
</location>
```

Config sections seem to be impossible to not inherit, but other parts of configuration can be "commented" out like this and don't get inherited.

Comment: There is an issue with this approach. You can disable inheritance of items in < system.web /> but this does nothing to the < configSections /> part. Anybody know how to disable inheritance of items in < configSections />?

Comment: I could not use "inheritInChildApplications" because VS didn't like it. What I did instead is negate the things IIS was complaining about by using a <remove ... /> tag. That worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

If you can use 2 separate application pools, you can completely stop inheritance by using an attibute `enableConfigurationOverride="false"` in the applicationHost.config file as I described in this question: [“Entry has already been added” - Two Separate App Pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367347/entry-has-already-been-added-two-separate-app-pools/24260655#24260655)

```
<add name="MyAppPool" enableConfigurationOverride="false" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" >
    <processModel identityType="NetworkService" />
</add>
```

Comment: No UI settings? Listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/

Comment: Was not able to use this approach in IIS 10, even when converting a top-level folder to a *new application* with a distinct application pool. The settings of the sub-application where still inherited from the main added.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion every time I've struggled with this the answer ends up being effectively NO - and I'm leaving this here for my future self to find so he doesn't waste any more time on it.

I've found this to be a huge problem when you just want to add something as a virtual directory inside an existing site. With a complex web.config files I've always just ended up giving up and moving it to a different application altogether.

Comment: are they fixing this in 'asp.next' or whatever that's all about?

Comment: I can't believe there is no way to globally override this! What a crock of s**t!

Answer (score 7):

I would explicitly define all of the settings required - never assume that any setting is still set to the default value.

For example, if you're defining a connectionString include a `<clear />` tag before the `<add name=... />`, etc. For Membership define all of the attributes, including the cookie name. And so on.

It may make the file a bit bigger but it will definitely help you avoid the "but it worked on my box" scenario too :-)

Comment: Not exactly what I'd expect a good answer to be, but maybe it's the least bad option ...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this situation a few times. It seems that the parent poster's instincts are in the ball park. I have found that adding two entries seem to have solved it—both a `<location>` entry.

1. Find your `<system.web>`…`</system.web>`. Wrap it with a `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">`.

   Now check the parent site and make sure it still works.
   Check the child: does it work or give an error?
2. If you still have an error, do the same thing with `<system.webserver>`; wrap the same `<location>` tag around it.

In summary - in the **PARENT**:

```xml
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>
    ...
  </system.web>
</location>
```

and maybe:

```xml
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webserver>
    ...
  </system.webserver>
</location>
```