# How to Prevent MVC 4 Child Application inheriting Parent Application (Umbraco MVC3) web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, umbraco

I have Umbraco deployed on the server. Currently I am trying to deploy MVC 4 Application as a child application but somehow the child's views\web.config inherits the configSections and sectionGroup from Umbraco's web.config. This results in the following error

> Section or group name 'system.web.webPages.razor' is already defined. Updates to this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined.

Umbraco's sectionGroup

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Child Application (MVC4) sectionGroup

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Probably view folder's web.config is inheriting from child app's web.config. If not, checkout this (http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2010/04/solved-iis7-validateintegratedmodeconfi.html) or this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228258%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @dereli It works when the sections are different but doesn't work with sectionGroup. Anyways have created the application in mvc3 now and it's working fine. Though its not a solution but a workaround for my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.  I resolved it by adding an assembly redirect for razor to my child application like this:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: you have helped me a lot...I have been look for an answer to this from a long time...Wish I could give you more points...

Comment: I had runtime binding of others bit not of System.Web.WebPages.Razor and I guess that was the problem. Anyways thanks a lotttt

Comment: for latest version: use latest version number: 3 for example:  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /> (look at your error message)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. Allow the inheritance and remove the sectionGroup from the child config(s) or something like this in any parent:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</location>
```

Intellisense may complain about this however but it should compile and run fine.

This question might also be of value: [Disable web.config inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367282/disable-web-config-inheritance)

Comment: Sorry Matt but it doesn't work. When it comes to sectionGroup, Location doesn't work. It was found in msdn that you cannot prevent inherit in sectionGroup. Probably you should see the answer that worked for me. Thanks anyways