# Section or group name 'system.web.webPages.razor' is already defined. Updates to this may only occur at the configuration level where it is defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

[image]While installing Orchard 1.9 I am having following parse error.I have updated NuGet packages for razor but still facing an error.Anyone knows how to remove this.
Thanks in advance.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <remove name="host" />
        <remove name="pages" />
        <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Comment: Edit your question and add web.config code

Comment: @RahulNikate please see this code gives error at sectionGroup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Prevent MVC 4 Child Application inheriting Parent Application (Umbraco MVC3) web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255667/how-to-prevent-mvc-4-child-application-inheriting-parent-application-umbraco-mv)

Comment: Please vote up for me if my question is helpful

Answer (score 4):

I believe this error occurs because you have the "sectionGroup", "system.web.webPages.razor" defined in two places. Remember that there is typically a "web.config" in the main solution(top level folder), and a "web.config" under the view folder:

[image]

Verify that a section group for "system.web.webPages.razor" is only defined in the "View\web.config", not in the main config file.